# How can I make it so my program, for each word read in a string, also reads the following word?

Tags: java, file-read

I want my Java program to do the following thing:
Whenever it reads a file like the following

```
Bob went to the store to buy apples.
```

To read each word in the string (delimited by only a single space character) and to also read the next word, but without "moving" the main reader as well. So it would do something like this:

```
for word in string{
     print word + nextWord;
}
```

And its output would be

```
Bob went
went to
to the
the store
store to
to buy
buy apples.
```

Edit: IMPORTANT! I don't want to read the whole file and load it into memory. I want this operation to happen DIRECTLY on the file. Imagine I am dealing with something huge, like a whole book, or more.

Comment: You might wanna have a look at this [Guide to `StreamTokenizer`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-streamtokenizer).

Comment: What is your file format? Is it split in rows? If so, can you read one row at a time?

Comment: "Huge" is relative; e.g. the KJV Bible is < 5M. Have you determined there's an actual memory issue? Is there any particular reason you can't use a normal buffered reader or a scanner?

Comment: Read the first word without printing. Store it as the lastWord. Read the next word. Print lastWord and the current word. Store the current word as the new lastWord. Read the next word, ...

Comment: It is split into rows, but I have to take into consideration that the next word could be on the next row. Also huge, huge. Imagine it is infinite. The point is, I need to do it by reading it live and live only, and cannot store it entirely in the memory at one time. File format, specifically, is .txt

Comment: You are expected to have made an attempt to solve your own problem before asking here.

Comment: I did, and came up with absolutely nothing. That is why I am asking here.

Comment: You haven't answered the questions I asked yet--without knowing why dealing w/ the file a line or chunk at a time it's impossible to help further.

Comment: This project that I am making is to demonstrate the use of Java Streaming, therefore I need to use that.

Comment: "I did, and came up with absolutely nothing." Nothing at all? That's hard to believe. E.g. there is BufferedReader.readLine() or lines(). With that you can read a file line by line without storing the whole file in memory. Or you can read characterwise with the read() method. Then you have only to deal with spaces and newlines (and maybe other whitespace) as word separators. Solve one problem at a time. First create a word reader. Then use the word reader to create the desired output (see my comment above).

Comment: I know I considered using BufferedReader but I need to specifically use Java Streams for it, and not the streams of bytes kind, but the .stream() kind... I did come up with stuff, there's at least 5 ways I'd do this way and much simpler but I am supposed to use a specific thing.

Comment: The lines() method gives you a Java Stream of strings (lines). (Read the documentation!) You can use this to transform this to a stream of words. You want to read from a file so have to use some kind of IO classes to achieve this.

Comment: Okay I'll try that and I'll tell you how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

No. Scanner doesn't let you peek at future input.

However, it's trivial to code:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("myfile.txt");
String previous = s.next();
while (s.hasNext()) {
    String next = s.next();
    System.out.println(previous + " " + next);
    previous = next;
}
```